# Как в стандартный поиск Wordpress добавить поиск по комментариям?

Tags: wordpress

Как в стандартный поиск Wordpress добавить поиск по комментариям?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/search+comment/

Answer (score 3):

Поиск в WordPress выполняется по постам. Комментарии хранятся в отдельной таблице и их можно получить с помощью объекта `WP_Comment_Query`. Добавить комментарии к результату поиска с помощью фильтра `the_posts` не получится, т.к. комментарии - это объекты другого типа.

Вам надо дополнить шаблон `search.php` таким запросом

```
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query( [ 'search' => get_search_query() ] );
$comments = $comments_query->comments;
```

И вывести массив объектов `$comments` так, как считаете нужным. Например

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->comment_content;
}
```